# Regular expression for sentences

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

My regular expression works well when there is a space after the dot.

```
$str = 'Fry me a Beaver. Fry me a Beaver! Fry me a Beaver? Fry me Beaver no. 4?! Fry me many Beavers... End';

$sentences = preg_split('/(?<=[.?!])\s+(?=[a-z])/i', $str);
```

But I need it to work as well, when there is a `\n` after the dot.

```
$str = 'Fry me a Beaver. Fry me a Beaver!\nFry me a Beaver? Fry me Beaver no. 4?! Fry me many Beavers... End';
```

I can't add a `\n` to the regular.

Comment: Why can't you??

Comment: You should try adding the multiline option via `/m` so `/(?<=[.?!])\s+(?=[a-z])/mi` might work.

Comment: `\n` in single quotes is a literal `\n` in PHP. Do you really have the above string? Demo https://3v4l.org/0AiLb

Comment: with `/m` not work

Comment: user3783243 has a point, are you sure you do not need the regex to work with `$str = "Fry me a Beaver. Fry me a Beaver!\nFry me a Beaver? Fry me Beaver no. 4?! Fry me many Beavers... End";`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew YES

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply add an `\\n`, chained to your `\s` with an OR (`|`):
`/(?<=[.?!])\s+|\\n+(?=[a-z])/i`

This can be seen working **[here](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/pSH)**.

Comment: At the risk of sounding silly; would `\s+|(\\r\\n)+|\\r+|\\n+` be appropriate?

Comment: `/(?<=[.?!])\s+|\\n+(?=[a-z])/i` is a corrupt pattern and won't do what is required.

Comment: It depends on *exactly* what OP is trying to target. For example, the `(?=[a-z])` will cause problems with the string `no. 4`. But it may matter what comes after the space.

Comment: Didn't you want to group that pipe `(\s+|\\n+)`?